# I want to add source from property file

Tags: java, struts2, struts-html

I have started using struts .I have hanged in a place ,Code is bellow

```
<st:submit src="getText('image.user.login')"  type="image" height="21" width="44" </st:submit>
```

when i run this code , **getText('image.user.login')** message does return any value , But when i replace **src="getText('image.user.login')"** with **value="getText('image.user.login')"** than it returns value of "image.user.login" from property file.

What is reason for it , and how can i solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in property file key value image.user.login=images/login.gif , i just want to pick image path from property file.

Comment: you should right it like this src="%{getText('image.user.login')}" is correct to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this example illustrates in this reference [submit reference struts](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/submit.html)

Render an image submit:

```
<s:submit type="image" value="%{'Submit'}" label="Submit the form" src="submit.gif"/>
```

src   : Supply an image src for image type submit button. Will have no effect for types input and button.

AND

value : String  Preset the value of input element.

this should answer your question if you use src you should assign a path and if you use value you can use a preset value

Comment: thanks , but value key value set in property file is image.user.login=images/login.gif , i just want to pick image path from property file.

Comment: you should right it like this `src="%{getText('image.user.login')}"` note the percent `%` and braces `{}` i read it on blogs and tutorials like (link)[http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/getText-did-not-return-value-in-s-submit-td3489503.html]

Comment: how did you make it work by adding percent and brace or not ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <st:submit key="image.user.login"/>
```